fingers do not moves like it must
fingers, or one part of the finger does not moving with bone right. i tryed to change face orientation, merged faces, changed vertex groups, but that doesnt work for me. Down here will be blend file, you can have a look at the model





That appears to be just a backup (.blend1) file of a chainsaw, not your human model.

Was this rigged in a software outside of Blender?

no, rig is mine, but 50% of mesh is not mine, however vertex groups are mine too

oh damn, there, now there is correct blend file
